# Why does every object of this class have the same value for its members?

Tags: java, static

I'm writting an application which should be extremely simple but it keeps using the last set values for `name` and `boxesSold` for everything. Here's a minimal example:

```
public class BandBoosterDriver
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    BandBooster booster1 = new BandBooster("First");
    BandBooster booster2 = new BandBooster("Second");
    booster2.updateSales(2);

    System.out.println(booster1.toString());
    System.out.println(booster2.toString());
  }
}
```

and here is the problem class:

```
public class BandBooster
{
  private static String name;
  private static int boxesSold;

  public BandBooster(String booster)
  {
    name = booster;
    boxesSold = 0;
  }

  public static String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }

  public static void updateSales(int numBoxesSold)
  {
    boxesSold = boxesSold + numBoxesSold;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
    return (name + ":" + " " + boxesSold + " boxes");
  }
}
```

This produces

```
Second: 2 boxes
Second: 2 boxes
```

But I would expect

```
First: 0 boxes
Second: 2 boxes
```

How can I get it to work the way I expect it to?

Comment: Read a tutorial on Object Oriented Programming with classes and objects. [This one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/) for instance.

Comment: `private static String name;` means that there's only one name per class.  Drop the `static`.

Comment: My searchfu is letting me down.. there must be a near-canonical question/answer we can mark this as a duplicate against.  It's not this one.. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class], that's not a dup.

Comment: Apologies for the major edit, but I couldn't find a duplicate, so I've updated this to be more generic, for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the static keyword.
    static will indicate your program to use single memory address for this field , and avoid allocating dedicated memory for this field everytime you create an instance of BandBooster.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I guess I just mixed definitions for static. The program runs fine now!

Comment: @user3067788 This answer solved your problem.  It is appropriate to click the tick to the left to reward the answerer for their efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Because it doesn't have any instance members, only static members.

Answer (score 0):

Statically created variables are unique to the class and shared by **all** instances of it. What you are seeing is what's supposed to happen.